# jquery run another action after first action finished

Tags: jquery

```
$("#btn").click(function(){   
    $('#text').text('foo'); 
    $("#btn").attr('disabled',true);//do this after text(); 
});
```

I have a button click will change element's text, and I need to disable this button after the text change, is any way to run `$().attr();` after `text();` completed

Comment: You can use callout function for this. Although Javascript is always synchronous and single-threaded meaning if you're executing a Javascript block of code on a page then no other Javascript on that page will currently be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#btn").click(function(){   
    $('#text').text('foo'); 
    $("#btn").attr('disabled','disabled');//do this after text(); 
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/23jtK/)